# Query all products without API, using wc_get_products in Woocommerce

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce, product

In Woocommerce I am trying to get all products using `wc_get_products()` as follow:

```
$args = array( 'status' => 'publish' );
$products = wc_get_products( $args );
return $products;
```

But it return an empty string.

How can I get all products using `wc_get_products()`? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you please put the full function that you are using not partial  code so we can know when the function is getting triggered, also did you try to `var_dump($products)`

Comment: Sorry I explained a worry situation... The function work but return an empty string.

Comment: @SalvatoreRiccardi Problem might be that Woocommerce wasn't initialized.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code works and will give you an array of the 10 last created `WC_Product` objects. So when you return this array of WC_Product objects, it gives nothing as it's not a string.

If you want **to get all products** you need to add `'limit'` argument with a value of **`-1`** like:

```
// An array of all published WC_Product Objects
$products = wc_get_products( array( 'status' => 'publish', 'limit' => -1 ) );

// Displaying the number of products in this array
echo '<p>Number of products: ' . sizeof( $products ) . '</p>';

// Loop through products and display some data using WC_Product methods
foreach ( $products as $product ){
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Type: '  . $product->get_type() . '<br>';  // Product type
    echo 'ID: '    . $product->get_id() . '<br>';    // Product ID
    echo 'Title: ' . $product->get_title() . '<br>'; // Product title
    echo 'Price: ' . $product->get_price();          // Product price
    echo '</p>';
}
```

Example - The following code will output in a string a coma separated suite of all your product IDs:

```
echo '<p>Products IDs list: ' . implode( ', ', wc_get_products( array( 'status' => 'publish', 'limit' => -1, 'return' => 'ids' ) ) ) . '</p>';
```

Tested and works.

Comment: It has returned yet an empty string with this syntax then pheraps is there a configuration problem? Is it possible? Are there a particulary mode where it doesn't work?

Comment: @SalvatoreRiccardi This answer code just works… So I don't know how and where you are using it. Your question is not clear related to the context  and usage.

Comment: Sorry, I found the problem. It's an undefined variable url that I initialize before and not the function. Thanks for the support.

Comment: I haven't resolved yet. Can you send me a zip file with your test code or post here it? Thanks.

Comment: @SalvatoreRiccardi I know that is quite late. I still want to write it down that nobody else would spend time figuring that out.

Comment: You just solved my problem that I wasted 2 hours on.

It was not clear to me, that `wc_get_products()` only returns 10 products if you do not specify anything else.

If you look at the source code: https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-product-functions.html, it is not documented there.

It is also not documented in the detailed usage description: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that

```
   wc_get_products($args);
```

wasn't initialized. You need to check that case first.
It might be that you add_action hook is having an inappropriate priority.
Make sure that woocommerce initialized first before calling that funciton.

Comment: Hey @Kairat Kempirbaev how do you initialise woocommerce? I think I'm having the problem you described in your answer.

Comment: @kadddeee https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/. I used functions.php in a child theme.